Go-Ethereum: shut down fails in handler.Stop(), anyone know why?
I'm running etclabscore/core-geth with my custom consensus engine (but reproduced the issue with Clique too). The shutdown process in handler.Stop() fails, and stops at h.wg.Wait().
func (h *handler) Stop() {
    [...]
    close(h.quitSync)
    h.peers.close()
    h.wg.Wait()

    log.Info("Ethereum protocol stopped")
} 

The h.quitSync channel is triggering shut down of protoTracker go-routine after all handlers have shut down (and it prevents opening new handlers, in incHandlers(). ) But, this process fails. For some reason, handlerDoneCh within the h.quitSync case is never triggered (from decHandlers()) and active never decrements to zero, and the protoTracker go-routine never closes, and h.wg.Wait() is therefore waiting forever.
func (h *handler) protoTracker() {
        [...]
        case <-h.quitSync:
            for ; active > 0; active-- {
                // It stops here, handlerDoneCh is never triggered, active never decrements
                <-h.handlerDoneCh
            }
            return
        }
    }
}

Thus I have to force close by using Ctrl+C 10 times...
I'll try and debug until I find what causes it. But if anyone knows, if similar problems are common and well known, feel free to explain the issue.
Edit: a workaround to this problem was found, see here. But it does not explain what causes it or how to really fix it.
